# Add new property in JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I am receiving a JSON Response from an external service. I am not deserializing it into an object. I wan to be able to add a new property to the JSON using C#.

Comment: Where is your JSON so we can see the format? What do you want to add to it? And why do you want to do what you are asking-there may be a better alternative.

Comment: Please clarify your question by showing concretely what you are doing and trying to do -- i.e. a [mcve].  You wrote, *I am not deserializing it into an object.*  Then, what **are** you doing?  What have you tried so far, and how is it not working?  What exception are you getting (if any)?  See [ask] for general guidelines on how to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra property into a serialized JSON string using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692523/10263)

Comment: How can you say it's unclear when he's already had two separate solutions proposed that produce identical results if you swap the test data sets? That's a _very_ sharply defined requirement.

Answer (score 6):

It's hard to give a proper answer with so few informations, but from the top of my head that's what I'd do

```
string json = "{\"Property1\":1}";

dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
d.Property2 = 2;

string new_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d);
```

You'd get `{"Property1":1, "Property2":2}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, direct string manipulation or using a library like http://www.newtonsoft.com/json which you can add to your project using NuGet.

If it's string manipulation and you don't want to parse then it will only be practical to append to the root object in the graph. Replace the last curly brace with your extra property:

```
using System;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  static class Program
  {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
      string s = "{ \"A\": \"val-A\" }";
      Console.WriteLine(s);
      s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1) + ", \"your-prop-name\": \"the-prop-value\" }";
      Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
  }
}
```

And the output:

```
{ "A": "val-A" }
{ "A": "val-A" , "your-prop-name": "the-prop-value" }
```

Comment: Anyone want to say why they think this is not an answer to the question? How else can you do it without parsing? If you get creative with Regex then you _are_ parsing. I've given a usable answer to the question. You two haven't.

Comment: I didn't dv, but I don't like seeing people suggest string manipulation for this kind of thing, and I think that's a common sentiment round here. Your first paragraph is the right answer (maybe it'd be better with code, but if OP wanted an energetic answer, he could have written a less lazy question). Maybe they dv'd without reading the whole thing; maybe they're just really on the warpath about it.

Comment: Also some people, if OP wants help doing something plain wrong, they don't think you should tell him to do it right instead.

Comment: Direct string manipulation for hierarchical data never did anyone any good

Comment: @MickyD - I did point out that it wouldn't be practical anywhere but the root object.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - maybe, but you don't know the context and neither do they. It may be the only way to squeeze fast post-processing into a Netduino serving as a PLC, where Json.NET is unavailable.

Comment: @PeterWone That's one reason I didn't dv. But when you hear hoofbeats, don't assume it's a zebra.

Comment: @EdPlunkett so a request for information that has a valid application gets a score of -1, and the only answer that addresses the question as asked gets a score of -3, SO is so uplifting.

Comment: I don't understand why this is downvoted this much. There are certain contexts where simple string manipulation is enough to meet your needs. One use case I have involves adding a single property and the alternative is to deserialize a sizeable object, add a property, then serialize it again which is overkill for what I'm trying to do. This is a completely valid solution as long as you understand the implications of adding it that way.

Comment: I love this solution! So simple and just what I was looking for!