# Adding property to GeoJSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, geojson

I have an excisting GeoJSON file, like this;

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Item": "Value"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              9.449194065548566,
              55.86046393906458,
              -999
            ],
            [
              9.460203211292942,
              55.8619238071893,
              -999
            ],
            [
              9.440463307997378,
              55.876740797773365,
              -999
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "Item": "Value"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              8.59655725301728,
              55.53506085541584,
              -999
            ],
            [
              8.601439658322603,
              55.52856219238175,
              -999
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to load this file, adding a property to each feature, and saving it as a new json file.
What would be the best way to go about this in C#?

I can load the file like so;

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/test.json")))
       {
           string json = r.ReadToEnd();
           List<RootObject> ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
       }
```

But, what then?

Comment: Deserialize json to models with additional property, set property, serialize to file.

Comment: As @brother pointed out you have to add the property before deserialization  set the property and then serialize it again

Comment: I know the theory behind, that i need to add the property, but how would i do that - do you have an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add an extra property into a serialized JSON string using json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18692523/10263)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the geojson file utilizing the OGR Library part of GDAL/OGR.
OGR is capable to directly read the geojson format:
http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/drv_geojson.html

Unluckily the documentation for the C# GDAL/OGR bindings is quite poor.

But you can have a look on how to access the geojson features with OGR in this sample:

https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/OGRFeatureEdit.cs

So you can use:

```
Ogr.RegisterAll(); // To register the OGR drivers especially geojson
DataSource ds = Ogr.Open(<path to your geojson>, 1 );
Layer layer = ds.GetLayerByName("the name of the layer");

// Finally iterate over all features you want to modify
Feature feature = layer.GetFeature(0);
feature.SetField(<set your fields>);

// write your feature back to your layer
layer.SetFeature(feature)
```

Comment: I cant use Newtonsoft.Json and/or GeoJSON.Net for the task instead, or?

Comment: You could also do it with another JSON Parser/reader/writer but since it is some kind of geo data I would do it with GDAL/OGR. Especially if you might want to change the projection of your geo data later or something like this; you'll not get around it ;-)

Comment: I dont want to change the Geodata - i only want to add a property to each feature, and then save it again, as a exact copy, with the new property added to each feature

Comment: As I wrote above you can modify each of your features with:
`Feature feature = layer.GetFeature(0);
feature.SetField(<set your fields>);`And after saving your layer you have the modified geojson with your additional property.

Comment: I cant find OGR on NuGet?

Comment: OGR is part of the GDAL library, which you can find here: [https://www.nuget.org/packages/GDAL/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GDAL/)